# App for scheduling resources like rooms or cars?

Tags: webapp-rec

We have a number of resources we'd like people to be able to reserve online -- things like company cars and meeting rooms. There are too many to create a Google or Exchange calendar for each. Are there any webapps that would fill this need?

Some details: the frontend doesn't need to be password protected. It would be nice if the system had an API or a way to export reservations, as well.

Comment: How many is too many? We do all of our room resource scheduling for 11 locations in Outlook.

Comment: I think 11 is about right, but we'll have clients who don't have access. What I want to avoid is having someone page through 11 calendars to find an open slot.

Answer (score 3):

[Google Calendar for Google Apps](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=1034362) allows you to do this if you have the Premier or Enterprise edition of Google Apps.

It looks like regular [Google Calendar](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=44105) allows you to do this as well.

In Google's vocabulary, these things are called "resources" and are usually rooms.